# Цикл в базе данных

Tags: sqlite3, sqlite, sql

Есть способ как создать цикличный запрос?

Comment: Эммм... можно поподробнее, что вы понимаете под циклическим запросом?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть Вы имеете в виду курсоры?

```
...
for rec in (select ...)
loop

end loop;
...
```

или pipelined функции?

Comment: сорри, имел ввиду oracle

Comment: Кусок кода, язык Pawn:

 Format(query, sizeof(query), "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM 'glav'");
 result = SQL_Query(DB, query);
 
 while(SQL_HasResultSet(result) && SQL_FetchRow(result)) {
  SQL_FetchString(result, 0, Name, 64);
  
  Format(query, sizeof(query), "SELECT id FROM 'glav' WHERE name ='%s' ORDER BY time LIMIT 10", Name);
  result2 = SQL_Query(DB, query);
  
  while(SQL_FetchRow(result2)) {
   SQL_FetchString(result2, 0, steamId_resrv, 32);
   
   if(StrEqual(Id_resrv, steamId)) { num++; }
  }
 }

Тут я ищу имя и делаю цикл по имени.
Просто там строк много и этот цикл нагружает сервер.

Answer (score 1):

Примеры таких "циклов" есть в документации SQLite.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(x) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM cnt WHERE x<1000000)
SELECT x FROM cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть `While`, например:

```
 declare @counter int
 set @counter = 0
 while @counter < 10
 begin
     set @counter = @counter + 1
      print 'The counter is ' + cast(@counter as char)
 end
```

Comment: Я имею ввиду запрос цикличный запрос!

Answer (score 0):

Искомые Вами данные можно получить одним запросом, цикл не нужен.

Не знаю, поддерживает ли SQLLite такие конструкции, проверьте:

```
select id
  from (select id, name
                   , row_number() over (partition by name order by time) rw
              from 'glav'
             )
        where rw <= 10
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но выдает ошибку (=
http://i32.fastpic.ru/big/2011/1001/53/95c60d68521b2415a31cf0081d2f1353.jpg

Comment: Я, к сожалению, не знаю особенностей синтаксиса SQLite, поэтому не смогу подсказать, единственный еще вариант - вот такой, он сработает в MS SQL:
select id
  from (select id, name
                   , row_number() over (partition by name order by time) rw
              from 'glav'
             ) as t
        where rw <= 10

Comment: Наши англоязычные друзья с ресурса, очень похожего на наш, говорят, что конструкция "row_number() over (partition by" в sqlite не сработает. Вот их беседа:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074257/sqlite-equivalent-of-row-number-over-partition-by

Comment: Да, не работает. Жалко. Может есть еще способы?

Comment: Я других не знаю, к сожалению.